# Is the derived category of coherent sheaves idempotent closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, coherent-sheaves, derived-categories

I am wondering whether the bounded derived category $D^b Coh(X)$ is idempotent complete, i.e. whether every idempotent morphism splits. This is true for $Perf(X)$ since perfect complexes are the compact objects in the category of quasi-coherent sheaves and compactness is preserved under taking retracts.

For example, if X is smooth, then $D^bCoh$ and $Perf$ agree and so
$D^b Coh$ is also idempotent closed.

Question : Are there any general conditions on a scheme X that imply that $D^b Coh$ is also idempotent closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's true if $X$ is Noetherian.

By [Prop. 36.11.2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08E0) of the Stacks Project, the natural functor
$$D^b\left(\text{Coh}(\mathcal{O}_X)\right)\to D^b_{\text{Coh}}(\mathcal{O}_X)$$
is then an equivalence, and $D^b_{\text{Coh}}(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is idempotent closed, since the category $\text{Coh}(\mathcal{O}_X)$ of coherent sheaves is abelian and therefore idempotent closed.